# Android private library is not available in java build path

Tags: android

I am using actionbarsherlock and my problem is following in one of my java classes: The type android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

People with similar problem could just check android private library in java build path but it's not an option for me. The thing is that everything worked but then I created a black activity and after that some things turned red.

Please help me figure out what the problem is.Just ask me if you need more information to solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking on your project->android tools->fix dependencies or **add support lib**
You should also make sure the lib is checked under order and export in project properties

Comment: I have added support lib and I have both cleaned the project and restarted eclipse.But I still don't have the option to check it in java build path.

Comment: Is the support lib ticked in libraries tab?

Comment: No, and it seems like I can't tick it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-order the build path of your project. It's under Java Build Path. Sometimes some private libraries are unchecked (for no reason). Check them again and shuffle a bit may solve the problem.

Comment: the thing is that android private library is not there so I can't check it.